# Prolog a kind of binary tree

Tags: prolog

so im trying to implement something that acts kinda like a tree.

Imagine i have 2 predicates, each one does a diferent thing, and i have a solution or i wanna find one, but there can be many ways to find one, using both 2 predicates, lets call them pred1 and pred2.

what im trying to do is like:

```
exercise(smtg, smtg):-
   answer(smtg), !.
exercise(smtg, ans):-
   pred1(smtg, newsmtg),
   exercise(newsmtg, ans).
exercise(smtg, ans):-
   pred2(smtg, newsmtg),
   exercise(newsmtg, ans).
```

so in my head what this would do is, explore all the possible combinations until it is a solution and then stop, but it doesnt work, probably im not thinking right, help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's your definition for answer?

Comment: its kind of abstract, its an example, like it would check if smtg is an answer and if it is then yeh

Comment: What is not working about your current solution?

Comment: it gets stuck in an infinite loop, it doesnt correctly do a "tree"

Comment: it only goes into the first condition, and only aplying the pred1 doesnt give me a answer

Comment: @false i invoke you

Comment: Your code has no variables.